# Accessing Message-Id property from internet header in Outlook 2007 macro

Tags: vba, outlook

In outlook 2007 macro I am able to access the internet header properties but I dont know how to point to the Message-Id property of it.Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: No, not without the code you've tried so far.

Comment: See https://www.slipstick.com/developer/read-mapi-properties-exposed-outlooks-object-model/ for the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
strHeaders = YourMailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F")
```

will extract the whole header

```
messageId = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F")
```

instead will only return the message-id property.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` to access PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS and parse it to extract the message id.

```
strHeaders = YourMailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F")
```